# Conflict when trying to initialize a priority queue using another comparison functor other than the one declared in the template signature

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

I implemented a templated priority queue:

```
template<typename TYPE, typename COMP_FUNCTOR = std::less<TYPE>>
class heap_priority_queue : public priority_queue<TYPE, COMP_FUNCTOR> {
public:
    typedef unsigned size_type;

    template<typename InputIterator>
    heap_priority_queue(InputIterator start, InputIterator end, COMP_FUNCTOR comp = COMP_FUNCTOR()); 
    /* other methods*/
};

template<typename TYPE, typename COMP_FUNCTOR>
template<typename InputIterator>
heap_priority_queue<TYPE, COMP_FUNCTOR>::heap_priority_queue (
    InputIterator start, InputIterator end, COMP_FUNCTOR comp) {

    for(auto it = start; it != end; ++it) {
        data.push_back(*it);
    }
    fix();
    this->compare = comp;
}
```

The default comparison functor defined in the template signature is std::less, but in the constructor of this priority_queue, it seems we can pass another custom COMP_FUNCTOR comp as the 3rd arguments, or we are using the COMP_FUNCTOR declared in the template signature? But when I tried to pass another COMP_FUNCTOR other than the one declared in the template signature as the third argument conflict happens,why? Here is the code:

```
class isgreater {
public:
    isgreater() {};
    bool operator () (int a, int b) {
        return a > b;
    }
};
int main() {
    int my_ints[] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
    vector<int> v(my_ints, my_ints + sizeof(my_ints)/sizeof(int));

    // wrong, default COMP_FUNCOR is std::less, which is different from isgreater;
    heap_priority_queue<int> sq(v.begin(), v.end(), isgreater());

    // right, no conflict
    heap_priority_queue<int, isgreater> back_up(v.begin(), v.end(), isgreater());
```

Why should the object we pass in as the third argument of the constructor  be the same as the one we declare in the template signature? It seems to me make no sense to keep the third argument of the constructor since we must use the one defined in the template signature...Thank you.

Comment: Hmm - type deduction is some heavy standardese. Right now, after 2 reads, it seems to me that COMP_FUNCTOR should be deduced from the types of the arguments to `sq` before falling back on the default template parameter value. You might want to consider tagging your question `language lawyer` and ask *why* the default template-argument type is used instead of deduction based on the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

```
// wrong, default COMP_FUNCOR is std::less, which is different from isgreater;
heap_priority_queue<int> sq(v.begin(), v.end(), isgreater());
```

is equal to

```
heap_priority_queue<int, std::less<int>> sq(v.begin(), v.end(), isgreater());
```

and compilator don't know how convert from isgreater to std::less<>

Comment: So the third argument of the constructor of this priority queue: COMP_FUNCTOR comp = COMP_FUNCTOR() means we can omit it and use COMP_FUNCTOR, or we can pass one by ourself, but the one we pass in must be the same as the one we declare in the template signature?

Comment: Thank you, then it seems to me make no sense to have the third argument in the function signature..

Comment: You mean class? Why? You could create an alias e.g. `using queue = heap_priority_queue<int, isgreater>;` and then just create instance of it: `queue  back_up(v.begin(), v.end());` So you don't need to explicity pass the comparator.

Comment: I mean in the implementation, we can do this->compare = COMP_FUNCTOR() directly, instead of this->compare = comp; Thus we can omit the third argument, right?

Comment: Yes, if you always want to have default comparator